# Are there only 81 levels in Tiny death Star?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have built 10/10/10/10/24/16 stages and I have no more options to build new ones. 
I have a bit more than 2,000,000 cash and under service i can see that there is a stage but it is locked...

Can anyone tell me if there is an option to go on in the game? It is totally boring to collect money build and build and can't get anything more...

Comment: the floor to my knowledge is a christmas one.

Answer (score 11):

Tiny Death Star is limited to the levels that the developers have released.  At the moment there are 81 regular levels as you have noted.  They also have released a special holiday update which has a new Service Level Panna City Medicine. The game does suggest that there will be future updates based upon the coming soons on the album pages.

Comment: So we can never get the 100 floors achievement...

Comment: @BenSloboda Not yet

Comment: Is there a 100 levels achievement?  There isn't one on iOS.

Comment: If you dig into the game code there are about 215 or so levels created but only 81 are currently available.

Answer (score 3):

As of today, February 17, 2014 you can have 93 floors,

- 11 Food
- 12 Service (including a limited edition one from an event during Christmastime)
- 11 Recreation
- 12 Retail (including a limited edition one, which closes tonight)
- 28 residential
- 18 Imperial

There's reason to think that more will be added for the next few Mondays.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, yes there are only 81 levels.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is all, congratulations you finished it!

After all that was one of the first games Disney developed to show the people they take the franchise seriously. Which they did - Tiny death star was highly praised by the Critics.

If you have all the Rooms and VIP´s than that's really it. 
If you like such games look at the Kairosoft games Mega Mall Story or Hot Spring Story. They are similar but different.

Comment: Kairosoft's games are really awesome. I haven't played Tiny Death Star a lot, but I think if you like that game, Kairosoft is a good developer to download some games from.

Answer (score 1):

"Panna City Medicine" is unlocked by having the Decorator Droid decorate 35 floors.  Once it's unlocked, Holiday Boba Fett (awarded at 20 decorated floors) unlocks the scene.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade.  This post does not really attempt to answer the question of the OP.  It would be a perfect answer to a question such as "How do you unlock Panna City Medicine and the cut-scene associated with it?".  Please read the tour section of the help tab, and I think you will come to enjoy being a contributor to this site.

Comment: @DavidM It Does somewhat answer, in that the OP does not seem to know about PCM and referenced an unknown locked floor. Not a real SE answer, but at least part of one. (Really saying this more for @redo1134.)

Comment: @MatthewFrederick - Yeah, I'll give you that.  But, I did give him the nice guy version of the comment . . .

Comment: @DavidM - Thanks for the welcome. The OP has edited the question. It originally included a sub-question about the Panna City Medicine level/cut-scene. Nevertheless, what I _should have done_ was respond in a comment on the OP rather than create a complete answer. (TY4 the nice guy version. I do appreciate it.)

Comment: @redo1134 My bad.  The welcome was real, though.  And, do please take the time to read the tour.  It's very helpful, and kind of funny.

Answer (score 1):

*Use the Source, Luke.*

While there are only 81 levels (+1 special), having a rummage around in the installation directory (Win8.1) `C:\program files\WindowsApps\LucasArts.TinyDeathStar_<version#>\Assets` we can see that game has:

- Costs associated with 200 levels (see below data dump).
- Images for 208 floors (I suspect some of these are Tiny Tower left-overs)
- lots of other miscellaneous stuff (characters that unlock cut-scenes etc).

```
{"cost":100,"number":2,"uid":"fc002"},
{"cost":200,"number":3,"uid":"fc003"},
{"cost":500,"number":4,"uid":"fc004"},
{"cost":650,"number":5,"uid":"fc005"},
{"cost":1000,"number":6,"uid":"fc006"},
{"cost":1650,"number":7,"uid":"fc007"},
{"cost":3150,"number":8,"uid":"fc008"},
{"cost":4400,"number":9,"uid":"fc009"},
{"cost":8600,"number":10,"uid":"fc010"},
{"cost":12150,"number":11,"uid":"fc011"},
{"cost":15000,"number":12,"uid":"fc012"},
{"cost":18150,"number":13,"uid":"fc013"},
{"cost":21600,"number":14,"uid":"fc014"},
{"cost":25350,"number":15,"uid":"fc015"},
{"cost":29400,"number":16,"uid":"fc016"},
{"cost":33750,"number":17,"uid":"fc017"},
{"cost":38400,"number":18,"uid":"fc018"},
{"cost":43350,"number":19,"uid":"fc019"},
{"cost":48600,"number":20,"uid":"fc020"},
{"cost":54150,"number":21,"uid":"fc021"},
{"cost":60000,"number":22,"uid":"fc022"},
{"cost":66150,"number":23,"uid":"fc023"},
{"cost":72600,"number":24,"uid":"fc024"},
{"cost":79350,"number":25,"uid":"fc025"},
{"cost":86400,"number":26,"uid":"fc026"},
{"cost":93750,"number":27,"uid":"fc027"},
{"cost":101400,"number":28,"uid":"fc028"},
{"cost":109350,"number":29,"uid":"fc029"},
{"cost":117600,"number":30,"uid":"fc030"},
{"cost":126150,"number":31,"uid":"fc031"},
{"cost":135000,"number":32,"uid":"fc032"},
{"cost":144150,"number":33,"uid":"fc033"},
{"cost":153600,"number":34,"uid":"fc034"},
{"cost":163350,"number":35,"uid":"fc035"},
{"cost":173400,"number":36,"uid":"fc036"},
{"cost":183750,"number":37,"uid":"fc037"},
{"cost":194400,"number":38,"uid":"fc038"},
{"cost":205350,"number":39,"uid":"fc039"},
{"cost":216600,"number":40,"uid":"fc040"},
{"cost":228150,"number":41,"uid":"fc041"},
{"cost":240000,"number":42,"uid":"fc042"},
{"cost":252150,"number":43,"uid":"fc043"},
{"cost":264600,"number":44,"uid":"fc044"},
{"cost":277350,"number":45,"uid":"fc045"},
{"cost":290400,"number":46,"uid":"fc046"},
{"cost":303750,"number":47,"uid":"fc047"},
{"cost":317400,"number":48,"uid":"fc048"},
{"cost":331350,"number":49,"uid":"fc049"},
{"cost":345600,"number":50,"uid":"fc050"},
{"cost":360150,"number":51,"uid":"fc051"},
{"cost":375000,"number":52,"uid":"fc052"},
{"cost":390150,"number":53,"uid":"fc053"},
{"cost":405600,"number":54,"uid":"fc054"},
{"cost":421350,"number":55,"uid":"fc055"},
{"cost":437400,"number":56,"uid":"fc056"},
{"cost":453750,"number":57,"uid":"fc057"},
{"cost":470400,"number":58,"uid":"fc058"},
{"cost":487350,"number":59,"uid":"fc059"},
{"cost":504600,"number":60,"uid":"fc060"},
{"cost":522150,"number":61,"uid":"fc061"},
{"cost":540000,"number":62,"uid":"fc062"},
{"cost":558150,"number":63,"uid":"fc063"},
{"cost":576600,"number":64,"uid":"fc064"},
{"cost":595350,"number":65,"uid":"fc065"},
{"cost":614400,"number":66,"uid":"fc066"},
{"cost":633750,"number":67,"uid":"fc067"},
{"cost":653400,"number":68,"uid":"fc068"},
{"cost":673350,"number":69,"uid":"fc069"},
{"cost":693600,"number":70,"uid":"fc070"},
{"cost":714150,"number":71,"uid":"fc071"},
{"cost":735000,"number":72,"uid":"fc072"},
{"cost":756150,"number":73,"uid":"fc073"},
{"cost":777600,"number":74,"uid":"fc074"},
{"cost":799350,"number":75,"uid":"fc075"},
{"cost":821400,"number":76,"uid":"fc076"},
{"cost":843750,"number":77,"uid":"fc077"},
{"cost":866400,"number":78,"uid":"fc078"},
{"cost":889350,"number":79,"uid":"fc079"},
{"cost":912600,"number":80,"uid":"fc080"},
{"cost":936150,"number":81,"uid":"fc081"},
{"cost":960000,"number":82,"uid":"fc082"},
{"cost":984150,"number":83,"uid":"fc083"},
{"cost":1008600,"number":84,"uid":"fc084"},
{"cost":1033350,"number":85,"uid":"fc085"},
{"cost":1058400,"number":86,"uid":"fc086"},
{"cost":1083750,"number":87,"uid":"fc087"},
{"cost":1109400,"number":88,"uid":"fc088"},
{"cost":1135350,"number":89,"uid":"fc089"},
{"cost":1161600,"number":90,"uid":"fc090"},
{"cost":1188150,"number":91,"uid":"fc091"},
{"cost":1215000,"number":92,"uid":"fc092"},
{"cost":1242150,"number":93,"uid":"fc093"},
{"cost":1269600,"number":94,"uid":"fc094"},
{"cost":1297350,"number":95,"uid":"fc095"},
{"cost":1325400,"number":96,"uid":"fc096"},
{"cost":1353750,"number":97,"uid":"fc097"},
{"cost":1382400,"number":98,"uid":"fc098"},
{"cost":1411350,"number":99,"uid":"fc099"},
{"cost":1440600,"number":100,"uid":"fc100"},
{"cost":1470150,"number":101,"uid":"fc101"},
{"cost":1500000,"number":102,"uid":"fc102"},
{"cost":1530150,"number":103,"uid":"fc103"},
{"cost":1560600,"number":104,"uid":"fc104"},
{"cost":1591350,"number":105,"uid":"fc105"},
{"cost":1622400,"number":106,"uid":"fc106"},
{"cost":1653750,"number":107,"uid":"fc107"},
{"cost":1685400,"number":108,"uid":"fc108"},
{"cost":1717350,"number":109,"uid":"fc109"},
{"cost":1749600,"number":110,"uid":"fc110"},
{"cost":1782150,"number":111,"uid":"fc111"},
{"cost":1815000,"number":112,"uid":"fc112"},
{"cost":1848150,"number":113,"uid":"fc113"},
{"cost":1881600,"number":114,"uid":"fc114"},
{"cost":1915350,"number":115,"uid":"fc115"},
{"cost":1949400,"number":116,"uid":"fc116"},
{"cost":1983750,"number":117,"uid":"fc117"},
{"cost":2018400,"number":118,"uid":"fc118"},
{"cost":2053350,"number":119,"uid":"fc119"},
{"cost":2088600,"number":120,"uid":"fc120"},
{"cost":2124150,"number":121,"uid":"fc121"},
{"cost":2160000,"number":122,"uid":"fc122"},
{"cost":2196150,"number":123,"uid":"fc123"},
{"cost":2232600,"number":124,"uid":"fc124"},
{"cost":2269350,"number":125,"uid":"fc125"},
{"cost":2306400,"number":126,"uid":"fc126"},
{"cost":2343750,"number":127,"uid":"fc127"},
{"cost":2381400,"number":128,"uid":"fc128"},
{"cost":2419350,"number":129,"uid":"fc129"},
{"cost":2457600,"number":130,"uid":"fc130"},
{"cost":2496150,"number":131,"uid":"fc131"},
{"cost":2535000,"number":132,"uid":"fc132"},
{"cost":2574150,"number":133,"uid":"fc133"},
{"cost":2613600,"number":134,"uid":"fc134"},
{"cost":2653350,"number":135,"uid":"fc135"},
{"cost":2693400,"number":136,"uid":"fc136"},
{"cost":2733750,"number":137,"uid":"fc137"},
{"cost":2774400,"number":138,"uid":"fc138"},
{"cost":2815350,"number":139,"uid":"fc139"},
{"cost":2856600,"number":140,"uid":"fc140"},
{"cost":2898150,"number":141,"uid":"fc141"},
{"cost":2940000,"number":142,"uid":"fc142"},
{"cost":2982150,"number":143,"uid":"fc143"},
{"cost":3024600,"number":144,"uid":"fc144"},
{"cost":3067350,"number":145,"uid":"fc145"},
{"cost":3110400,"number":146,"uid":"fc146"},
{"cost":3153750,"number":147,"uid":"fc147"},
{"cost":3197400,"number":148,"uid":"fc148"},
{"cost":3241350,"number":149,"uid":"fc149"},
{"cost":3285600,"number":150,"uid":"fc150"},
{"cost":3330150,"number":151,"uid":"fc151"},
{"cost":3375000,"number":152,"uid":"fc152"},
{"cost":3420150,"number":153,"uid":"fc153"},
{"cost":3465600,"number":154,"uid":"fc154"},
{"cost":3511350,"number":155,"uid":"fc155"},
{"cost":3557400,"number":156,"uid":"fc156"},
{"cost":3603750,"number":157,"uid":"fc157"},
{"cost":3650400,"number":158,"uid":"fc158"},
{"cost":3697350,"number":159,"uid":"fc159"},
{"cost":3744600,"number":160,"uid":"fc160"},
{"cost":3792150,"number":161,"uid":"fc161"},
{"cost":3840000,"number":162,"uid":"fc162"},
{"cost":3888150,"number":163,"uid":"fc163"},
{"cost":3936600,"number":164,"uid":"fc164"},
{"cost":3985350,"number":165,"uid":"fc165"},
{"cost":4034400,"number":166,"uid":"fc166"},
{"cost":4083750,"number":167,"uid":"fc167"},
{"cost":4133400,"number":168,"uid":"fc168"},
{"cost":4183350,"number":169,"uid":"fc169"},
{"cost":4233600,"number":170,"uid":"fc170"},
{"cost":4284150,"number":171,"uid":"fc171"},
{"cost":4335000,"number":172,"uid":"fc172"},
{"cost":4386150,"number":173,"uid":"fc173"},
{"cost":4437600,"number":174,"uid":"fc174"},
{"cost":4489350,"number":175,"uid":"fc175"},
{"cost":4541400,"number":176,"uid":"fc176"},
{"cost":4593750,"number":177,"uid":"fc177"},
{"cost":4646400,"number":178,"uid":"fc178"},
{"cost":4699350,"number":179,"uid":"fc179"},
{"cost":4752600,"number":180,"uid":"fc180"},
{"cost":4806150,"number":181,"uid":"fc181"},
{"cost":4860000,"number":182,"uid":"fc182"},
{"cost":4914150,"number":183,"uid":"fc183"},
{"cost":4968600,"number":184,"uid":"fc184"},
{"cost":5023350,"number":185,"uid":"fc185"},
{"cost":5078400,"number":186,"uid":"fc186"},
{"cost":5133750,"number":187,"uid":"fc187"},
{"cost":5189400,"number":188,"uid":"fc188"},
{"cost":5245350,"number":189,"uid":"fc189"},
{"cost":5301600,"number":190,"uid":"fc190"},
{"cost":5358150,"number":191,"uid":"fc191"},
{"cost":5415000,"number":192,"uid":"fc192"},
{"cost":5472150,"number":193,"uid":"fc193"},
{"cost":5529600,"number":194,"uid":"fc194"},
{"cost":5587350,"number":195,"uid":"fc195"},
{"cost":5645400,"number":196,"uid":"fc196"},
{"cost":5703750,"number":197,"uid":"fc197"},
{"cost":5762400,"number":198,"uid":"fc198"},
{"cost":5821350,"number":199,"uid":"fc199"},
{"cost":5880600,"number":200,"uid":"fc200"}],
```

Comment: If you want to cheat find the game.txt file. Look for "coins" and "credits". Make the numbers large. Of course it completely ruins the fun, but that's your choice. `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Packages\LucasArts.TinyDeathStar_RANDOMJUNK\LocalState\game.txt`